# asp.net grid view

Tags: asp.net, view, grid

Can i format GridView as the following figure

---

```
                      100 ml  TextBox1  TextBox2
          Product A 
                      200 ml  TextBox3  TextBox4

                      100 ml  TextBox1  TextBox2
          Product A 
                      200 ml  TextBox3  TextBox4
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you can find solution [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/take-row-level-control-of-your-gridview/). The main rule here is handling GridView1_RowDataBound event for GridView where you can control rows appearence.

Answer (score 0):

For the last two columns you can have template columns with textboxes inside them, while for the first you can merge cells setting appropriate colspan/rowspan wiring the OnRowCreated event of the GridView.